# What is reasonable way to reject outliers from dataset?

Tags: outliers

I have small dataset of 5 samples: [ 0.95,0.9,0.05,0.92,0.9] the mean is 0.74 and stdev is 0.38. Is it reasonable to say samples that are 2 standard deviations further from the mean are outliers and can be removed?

Later I need to find the minimum of the dataset. Is it possile than for example to remove 0.05 and say the mininmum is 0.9?

Gathering more data is hard. I can get 10 samples but more difficult. How would you approach this problem if you had more samples as well?

Thank you

Comment: A dataset with 5 samples and you are speaking about outliers? I would definetely **not** exclude any data, except they are outliers due to measurement errors.

Comment: As Shenflow indicates Outlier rejection is a very sticky subject and is only realistic when there is a much larger body of evidence and even then must be handled with care. If you have a much larger number of samples, each with 5 reps and you can easily demonstrate that the others are much more consistent then there may be some room for argument. Outlier rejection in quality control is based on this principle, but it is important to note, as Shenflow suggests, it is still important to diagnose the cause of outliers. Blind rejection is a no no.

Comment: Ok, how would you approach the problem if you had larger dataset? Is what I've described ok in that case?

Comment: @greensquare The answer depends on what you want to do with the remaining data. You need to tell us the goal behind your modeling effort.

Comment: @greensquare Totally speculative here, suppose these 5 data points are the fraction of cancer patients who survived the treatment of 5 different drugs, then point 3 (0.05) takes on vastly different significance than the other four.